# TypeORM service name connection option for Oracle

Tags: oracle, connection-string, typeorm

I'm trying to connect to a RAC environment, but I need to connect using the service name... It looks like this options isn't provided in the connection options provided by typeORM.

Here's the connection string on my SQL Client DBeaver

[image]

And this is my typeorm connection config.

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: "oracle",
      host: "localhost",
      port: 1521,
      extra: {
          "SERVICE_NAME": "node.localdomain"
      },
      username: "hr",
      password: "root",
      database: "orcl",
      entities: [Employee],
      synchronize: false,
    }),
    GraphQLModule.forRoot({
      debug: true,
      playground: true,
      autoSchemaFile: 'schema.gpl'
    }),
    EmployeesModule
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 1):

So it looks like there is a property named `serviceName`, I guess it's part of oracle's database driver.

Answer (score 1):

Use parameter `connectString` instead.